# progression bar in simple_form using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working on a project using ruby 2 and rails 4. I want to create a progression bar in simple_form. I got some resources from https://github.com/aarondo/progression.js/blob/master/demo/index.html
and it does work perfectly. But it was created using html, and  i want to create using simple_form_for. My codes are:

```
<%= simple_form_for @kyc do |f| %>

<h2>Personal Information</h2>

<%= f.input :first_name , placeholder: 'Type Your First Name', label:'First Name', required: true, input_html: { :value => ''}, autofocus: true %>
<%= f.input :last_name , placeholder: 'Type Your Last Name', label:'Last Name', required: true, input_html: { :value => ''} %>  
<%= f.input :pan , placeholder: 'Type Your PAN No', label:'PAN', required: true, input_html: { :value => ''} %>

<p align="center"><%= f.submit "Save", id: "kycs_button" %></p>

<% end %>
```

Can any one please help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: That progression bar, I am not able to create using simple_form. see the demo in this link.But he used html. But i want to use simple_form. http://git.aaronlumsden.com/progression/

Comment: Coudl you maybe provide the html output of simple_form?

Comment: Try adding `:data => {:progression => true}` to the input_html part of input definitions. like: `<%= f.input :first_name , placeholder: 'Type Your First Name', label:'First Name', required: true, input_html: { :value => '', :data => {:progression => true}}, autofocus: true %>`

Comment: no.. it does not work.

Comment: Did you actually add the `$("#id_of_the_simple_form_here").progression();` to document ready ?

Comment: Thank you Manoj Monga. Ya I was using my manual id. But now its working when i am using id which created by simple_form itself. Thank you thanks a lot. and thank you to all of you who came to help me.

Comment: You're welcome bud :)

Comment: The progression bar does work when i use f.input, but it does not work when i use f.text_field.     `<%= f.text_field :date_of_birth, :autocomplete => :off, :data => {:progression => true, :helper => "Write your date of birth,"}  %>`  Do you know about this problem?

Comment: hoo... done. f.text_field containing codes had to keep inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can spot right away is that you did not put the `data-progression` attribute in and you didn't put the `data-helper`

If you ommit the `data-progression` attribute, the progress-bar always stays at 0%

Comment: The thing is my bar is not coming. Even i added data-progression in inspect element(in google crome) but does not show anything.

Comment: Do all the javascript resrouces get loaded properly, or do you maybe have a link to some js-resource that cannot be loaded?

Comment: All the javascript resources are working properly. Because on same page progression bar is working using html. But no effect in simple_form.

Comment: i am giving you the link. I want something like this using simple_form.he used html. http://git.aaronlumsden.com/progression/

Comment: I get that, but I think some more of your code is needed, to be able to help you.

Comment: please see this code. Everything i have added and it works smoothly. but when i remove html code and put my code which i have already posted, then it does not work, even i added the id "myform" in simple_form once a time. https://github.com/aarondo/progression.js/blob/master/demo/index.html

Comment: that's beacause progression.js.min is relative link, you'll have to get your own copy of the js file and refernce it properly